# Can I use sharing for satellite card with Dial UP Conniction

Tags: internet, tuner-card, satellite

I want to buy a SkyStar card to view satellite channels in my PC , I'm planning to use **Sharing servers** to view all JSC Sport channels.

Can I  use **sharing service with Dial up Connection** (40 k.b) , Will the picture gone from time to time ? or it will work perfectly ?Have I use ADSL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing over LAN using progdvb-server is slow (and single channel) ! so using dial-up is very slow,and if you want to share this channel you have to use a third-party application to compress and decrease quality in real-time to broadcast,

Comment: I just want to get codes , I don't want to share my channel , I mean i want to be just a client (getting without giving) , is that possible?